# How to configure java server based on sockets (non http ) with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, applet

I'm currently developing a web server based on sockets for a web game.
*The client will be based on Java applet*.

1. Is it possible to use Apache Tomcat server for this mission?

   If it is possible, could you recommend us a step by step guide for how to configure it?
2. Do you think that we should use alternative server for that?
3. Will it be easier to implement this using servlets (http requests) and Google Application Engine?

Comment: Any reason you cannot just communicate over a http 1.1 connection staying open?

Comment: What is the meaning of using only http 1.1 .                         Far as I know serverlets are already using http 1.1

Comment: Your client needs to ask for a 1.1 connection.  Are you familiar with network programming?

Comment: If you want to create a public internet game you should consider HTTP 1.1 with some lightweight RESTful protocol, e.g. JSON. Otherwise ServerSocket is what you need (has nothing to do with Servlet): http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write your own connector and protocol handler for tomcat if you need another protocol than http.

In this case try [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Servlets and Tomcat, but you can simply start the server as a standalone Java program, opening a ServerSocket to listen on the port. On each connection, split off a new Thread with will read from the new Connection.

For greater scalability, use nonblocking IO and a selector instead of a separate thread for each connection.